# How to achieve a gap in a border

Tags: jquery, html, css, border

I'm trying to achieve a break/gap in a border using css (border) and am wondering what the best ways to do it is. Here's an example of what I'm after.

[image: Border with gap in it]

Comment: That would depend almost entirely on what the HTML is, so please: show us the ("*[MCVE]*") HTML for your page.

Comment: Div and background keep it relative and logo position absolute with top and left

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31301716/overlap-border-of-parent-with-h2-margin-negative

Comment: And this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31205386/how-to-add-border-to-a-container-with-transparent-gaps-in-between/31205824#31205824 I am wondering which one to use for closure :P

Comment: Also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35030493/incomplete-borders-around-div/35030587#35030587

Comment: @DavidThomas - Here's a rough idea of the mark-up I want to use - https://jsfiddle.net/7202y8bc/

Comment: Thanks @pangloss that's exactly what I'm after